# Change table data value using jQuery and userscript

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome, userscripts, tampermonkey

I am trying to change table data value using jQuery and userscript but its not working. Here's my code:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name       My Fancy New Userscript
// @namespace  http://use.i.E.your.homepage/
// @version    0.1
// @description  enter something useful
// @copyright  2012+, You
// ==/UserScript==


// a function that loads jQuery and calls a callback function when jQuery has finished loading
function addJQuery(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', function() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.textContent = "window.jQ=jQuery.noConflict(true);(" + callback.toString() + ")();";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
  }, false);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
}

// the guts of this userscript
function main() {
  // Note, jQ replaces $ to avoid conflicts.
 $('.last').html('111');
}

// load jQuery and execute the main function
addJQuery(main);
```

What am I doing wrong? I am using the Tampermonkey extension on Chrome 30.0.1599.69

Answer (score 1):

The *immediate* thing wrong with that code is that `$('.last').html('111');` needs to be `JQ('.last').html('111');`

`addJQuery()` defines `JQ`, not `$` inside `main()` and that is not the best version of `addJQuery()`.

---

But, the bigger issue is **that is not a smart way to use jQuery** on Tampermonkey (or Greasemonkey).  Keep your script isolated from the page's code when you can.

Your entire script should be something like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _YOUR_SCRIPT_NAME
// @include  http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js
// @version  0.1
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
/*- The @grant directive is needed to work around a design change
    introduced in GM 1.0.   It restores the sandbox.
*/
$('.last').html ('111');
```

Be sure to match the `@include` directive(s) to your target pages.